# Download files with netty

Tags: java, download, netty

I am creating a very basic webserver using netty and java. I will have basic functionality. It's main responsibilities would be to serve responses for API calls done from a client (e.g a browser, or a console app I am building) in JSON form or send a zip file. For that reason I have created the HttpServerHanddler class which is responsible for getting the request, parsing it to find the command and call the appropriate api call.It extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler

and overrides the following functions;

```
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    LOG.debug("channelActive");
}

@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    LOG.debug("In channelComplete()");
    ctx.flush();
}

@Override
public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)
        throws IOException {
    ctx = processMessage(ctx, msg);
    if (!HttpHeaders.isKeepAlive(request)) {
        // If keep-alive is off, close the connection once the content is
        // fully written.
        ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(
                ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    }

}


private ChannelHandlerContext processMessage(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg){
    if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
        HttpRequest request = this.request = (HttpRequest) msg;

        if (HttpHeaders.is100ContinueExpected(request)) {
            send100Continue(ctx);
        }
        //parse message to find command, parameters and cookies
        ctx = executeCommand(command, parameters, cookies)
    }
    if (msg instanceof LastHttpContent) {
        LOG.debug("msg is of LastHttpContent");
        if (!HttpHeaders.isKeepAlive(request)) {
            // If keep-alive is off, close the connection once the content is
            // fully written.
            ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(
                ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        } 
    }
    return ctx;
}

private ChanndelHandlerContext executeCommand(String command, HashMap<String, List<String>>> parameters, Set<Cookie> cookies>){
    //switch case to see which command has to be invoked
    switch(command){
    //many cases
    case "/report":
        ctx = myApi.getReport(parameters, cookies); //This is a member var of ServerHandler
        break;
    //many more cases
    }
    return ctx;
}
```

In my Api class that has the getReport function.

getReport

```
public ChannelHandlerContext getReportFile(Map<String, List<String>> parameters,
                                           Set<Cookie> cookies) {

    //some initiliazations. Actual file handing happens bellow
    File file = new File(fixedReportPath);
    RandomAccessFile raf = null;
    long fileLength = 0L;

    try {
        raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
        fileLength = raf.length();
        LOG.debug("creating response for file");
        this.response = Response.createFileResponse(fileLength);
        this.ctx.write(response);

        this.ctx.write(new HttpChunkedInput(new ChunkedFile(raf, 0,
                                                            fileLength,
                                                            8192)),
                this.ctx.newProgressivePromise());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {

        LOG.debug("File was not found", fnfe);
        this.response = Response.createStringResponse("failure");
        this.ctx.write(response);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        LOG.debug("Error getting file size", ioe);
        this.response = Response.createStringResponse("failure");

        this.ctx.write(response);
    } finally {
        try {
            raf.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return this.ctx;
}
```

Response class is responsible for handling various types of response creations (JsonString JsonArray JsonInteger File, etc)

```
public static FullHttpResponse createFileResponse(long fileLength) {
    FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK);
    HttpHeaders.setContentLength(response, fileLength);
    response.headers().set(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/octet-stream");
    return response;
}
```

My Api works great for my Json responses(easier to achieve) but It won't work well with my json responses, but not with my file response. When making a request from e.g chrome it only hangs and does not download the file. Should I do something else when downloading a file using netty? I know its not the best wittern code, I still think I have some bits and pieces missing from totally understanding the code, but I would like your advice on how to handle download on my code. For my code I took under consideration [this](http://goo.gl/JUhEjD) and [this](http://goo.gl/cEtwR3)

Answer (score 1):

First, some remarks on your code...

Instead of returning ctx, I would prefer to return the last Future for the last command, such that your last event (no keep alive on) could use it directly.

```
public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)
    throws IOException {
  ChannelFuture future = processMessage(ctx, msg);
  if (future != null && !HttpHeaders.isKeepAlive(request)) {
    // If keep-alive is off, close the connection once the content is
    // fully written.
    future.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
  }
}
```

Doing this way will allow to directly close without having any "pseudo" send, even empty.

**Important:** Note that in Http, the response is managed such that there are chunk send for all data after the first HttpResponse item, until the last one which is empty (LastHttpContent). Sending another empty one (Empty chunk but not LastHttpContent) could break the internal logic.

Moreover, you're doing the work twice (once in `read0`, once in `processMessage`), which could lead to some issues perhaps.

Also, since you check for KeepAlive, you should ensure to set it back in the response:

```
if (HttpHeaders.isKeepAlive(request)) {
  response.headers().set(CONNECTION, HttpHeaders.Values.KEEP_ALIVE);
}
```

On your send, you have 2 choices (depending on the usage of SSL or not): you've selected only the second one, which is more general, so of course valid in all cases but less efficient.

```
// Write the content.
ChannelFuture sendFileFuture;
ChannelFuture lastContentFuture;
if (ctx.pipeline().get(SslHandler.class) == null) {
  sendFileFuture =
    ctx.write(new DefaultFileRegion(raf.getChannel(), 0, fileLength), ctx.newProgressivePromise());
  // Write the end marker.
  lastContentFuture = ctx.writeAndFlush(LastHttpContent.EMPTY_LAST_CONTENT); // <= last writeAndFlush
} else {
  sendFileFuture =
    ctx.writeAndFlush(new HttpChunkedInput(new ChunkedFile(raf, 0, fileLength, 8192)),
      ctx.newProgressivePromise()); // <= last writeAndFlush
  // HttpChunkedInput will write the end marker (LastHttpContent) for us.
  lastContentFuture = sendFileFuture;
}
```

This is this lastContentFuture that you can get back to the caller to check the KeepAlive.

Note however that **you didn't include a single flush** there (except with your ***EMPTY_BUFFER but which can be the main reason of your issue*** there!), contrary to the example (from which I copied the source).
Note that both use a writeAndFlush for the last call (or the unique one).